# progress bar in appwidget for a playback service

Tags: android, service, android-appwidget

I wanted to display a progress bar in an appwidget that displays playback progress from a background service. I know the appwidget supports that control, but I am wondering how I might go about updating the progress bar in a way that is consistent with good widget design (e.g. low battery consumption). The way I would normally do it in an activity would be by polling the playback on a timer. I haven't implemented this yet, so I am not even sure if it would work in an appwidget. Anyone know better than me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the service update the app widget's `RemoteViews` when sufficient time has elapsed to make it worthwhile to update.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I broadcast an intent to the remoteview

Comment: @Jonathan S.: No, I am suggesting that you have the service update the app widget's `RemoteViews`. Use `AppWidgetManager` for this, same as you would any other place where you update the app widget's `RemoteViews`.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the confusion, I had tried this before,  and the launcher essentially ground to a halt. I guess there is no way to update as often as I would like efficiently (once every second or couple of seconds), so I will have to play around until I find a usable value.

Comment: @Jonathan S.: Once every second will be bad for all. Once every minute should be tolerable.

Comment: Unfortunately these can be very short clips that are playing, so I will probably get rid of the progress bar altogether. This would explain the reason that there are no progress bars in most mediaplayer widgets.