# Show ProgressBar in an AppWidget that updates every second

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I've been researching on the topic before implementing it.
Thing is, mine is a music player app for which I'm making a widget, to control music playback. I wanted to put a `SeekBar` in the widget but that's not supported. `ProgressBar` is supported but there are hardly any widgets that use one. So I'm skeptical of how using a `ProgressBar` would effect my user's phone's performance (in terms of battery life and memory usage).

Since the `ProgressBar` is meant to display current position of the music playing, it would have to be updated every second. I read here [progress bar in appwidget for a playback service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946814/progress-bar-in-appwidget-for-a-playback-service?rq=1) that updating a widget's `ProgressBar` every second is a bad idea. But the post is more than 4 years old. Couldn't find anything newer.

Question is, is it still a bad idea to use a `ProgressBar`, that updates every second, in an app widget? Or have the latest android updates brought in any new ways to do this efficiently? If yes, then how do we go about it?

Any guidance would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> Question is, is it still a bad idea to use a ProgressBar, that updates every second, in an app widget?

In general, it is a bad idea to update an app widget every second, regardless of whether this involves a `ProgressBar` or not. Frequent IPC is inefficient, particularly since you do not know whether the user can even see the `ProgressBar`.

That being said, in your use case, if you only ever update the `ProgressBar` while your app is playing music, the power drain of the app widget IPC will be dwarfed by the power drain of the music playback.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The ProgressBar would be updated only when my app is playing music. Now how should I go about it? I mean is it possible to keep a reference of the ProgressBar and use it to update it in a thread. or it's needed every time to create a RemoteView with the updated progress and use it to update the widget?

Comment: @Anjani: "I mean is it possible to keep a reference of the ProgressBar and use it to update it in a thread" -- the `ProgressBar` is not in your process; you never have a reference to it. "or it's needed every time to create a RemoteView with the updated progress and use it to update the widget?" -- AFAIK, yes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. I'll just let this question stay up for a day or two so that someone else can also shares his/her opinion on the matter. Otherwise I'll accept this one. Thanks again.